# How do I accumulate repeated application of a function to a list of values?

Tags: list, haskell

How do I accumulate the successive application of a function to a list of values in Haskell?

I'm not sure I'm phrasing that right, but what I'm looking for, for example, is that I have a list values of type `X`,

```
l = [a, b, c, d, e]
```

and a function

```
f :: X -> X -> X
```

and I want

```
(f e (f d (f c (f b a))))
```

which I think can perhaps be expressed with `$` somehow.

I see that Haskell has some `fold` functions, but I can't quite figure out how to get it to work like the [fold operations I'm familiar with](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html).

Comment: What do you want to happen if the list is empty or only has one element.

Comment: Did you mean to write `f b a`?

Comment: A good starting point for questions like this is (and really anything in haskell) is to think carefully about the type signature that you want. If you can't write the signature then you don't really know what you want. You might then type it into hoogle and find that it's already been written

Comment: Did you mean to use `d` twice?

Comment: @dfeuer: Yes, I really messed up the question!

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: No. Sloppy question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Play with [`simple-reflect`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/simple-reflect-0.3.2/docs/Debug-SimpleReflect.html) to figure it out.

```
ghci> import Debug.SimpleReflect
ghci> foldl1 f [a,b,c,d,e]
f (f (f (f a b) c) d) e
ghci> foldl (flip f) z [a,b,c,d,e]
f e (f d (f c (f b (f a z))))
```

And so on...

Comment: Wow, I had no idea I could do that. That makes learning Haskell so much simpler! ("teach a man to fish ...")

Answer (score 6):

Isn't this just `foldl1 (flip f) l`? You want a left fold, and you want the operation to start with the first item in the list rather than a specific accumulator.

Answer (score 5):

Well, your function `f` really has type:

```
f :: X -> X -> X
```

Then the expression you are interested in is:

```
foldr1 f [e, d, c, a, b]  -- note the twist at the end.
```

If you want to compute:

```
f e (f d (f c (f b a)))  -- note last term is: f b a
```

then it is just:

```
foldr1 f [e, d, c, b, a]
```